# A single sign on authentication in golang

Tags: authentication, go, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am trying to build a multi-tenant architecture in `golang` where there will be different services like `Service-A` and `Service-B` each service will run on a different server and I want the user to have a `single sign-in`  solution and get authenticated in all the services offered.

Just like what `Amazon AWS or Google` does like it has many different services like `Amazon Cloud Front`, `Amazon EC2`, `Amazon S3` and all services are authenticated through a single login and logout from one service result in`log out from all connected services`.

I am trying to implement this in `golang`, so far I found out `Open-id Connect` [coreos/dex](https://github.com/coreos/dex) 
but it lacks docs explaining its API and Architecture.

**What would be the best architecture to design such authentication system?**

I think using `JWT token` I can achieve it. `Is this architecture will be secure or there any better solution for this`?

> My Approach

```
                          -----------------        
                          |               |    shared
                          |               |   env file
                          |SERVICES A     |---------------|       
           AUTH HEADER    |               |               |
           JWT TOKEN      |               |               |
        |---------------> -----------------               |                     
    ---------            ------------------   shared      |
    |       |            |    SERVICE B   |  env file     |                    
    |Login  | -----------|                |-----------    |               
    |Browser|            |                |          |    |  
    ---------            ------------------          |    |
        | |                                          |    |   
   Login| |"JWT_TOKEN RESPONSE"                      |    |   
        | |                                          |    |   
    --------------   enviroment file                ------------   
    |            |----------------------------------|          |
    | Main Server|                                  |          |
    |            |                                  |JWT_SECRET|    
    --------------                                  |="secret" |          
                                                    ------------
```

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @jurgemaister I am editing and adding details  this will make easily for you to answer.

Comment: @jurgemaister I have edited please check it now

Comment: only I can say, your Approach should work.

Comment: @JiangYD is there any better approach other than this?

Comment: *better* is a subjective term.  there are many other options, and as @JiangYD said, the only thing we can say to a question this broad is, "your approach should work, as one option"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your solution will certainly work. It could make writing the browser/mobile/general **frontend** part of your application more complex. And possibly slower.

For example you might end up effectively JOINing data in the frontend. You make one request to service A, then use the information returned there to make additional requests to service B. This is a bad experience for the user.

Once new concept that companies like Netflix and Soundcloud are pioneering is the [backend for frontend pattern](http://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/). Which is a server side adaptor for each type of frontend device that can handle authentication and aggregate the connections to the down stream services.